# Why is this image broken when loaded online but when I preview it is fine?

Tags: html, css, lightbox

I am working on a gallery page for my sister-in-laws website and when I check the website simply by opening the '.html' file in Chrome, Firefox and Explorer the image loads perfectly but when I published the website it no longer works. I copied the code for a makeshift lightbox, but I cannot find the page that I copied it from.

Here's the html code:

```
<!--Lightboxes-->
    <div id="outdoors1" class="outdoor1_content">
        <img src="images/gallery/outdoor/1.jpg" width="600" height="450"/>
        <a href="outdoor.html" onclick ="document.getElementById('outdoors1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'" style="color:#333333"><div id="closetext"><img src="images/gallery/closebutton.png" width="40" height="40"/></a></div></a>
    </div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
    <div class="outdoor_container">
        <div class="outdoor_container2">
            <div id="outdoor1">
                <img src="images/gallery/outdoor/outdoor1.jpg" width="170" height="170" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('outdoors1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';"/>
            </div>
```

I only included code for one of the images as it is just repeated multiple times for each gallery page.

Here's the CSS:

```
    /*Lightbox content placement*/
    .black_overlay{
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:0%;
        left:0%;
        width:100%;
        height:1530px;
        background-color:black;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity:0.8;
        opacity:.80;
        filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    }
    #closetext{
        position:relative;
        float:left; 
    }

#outdoor1{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 190px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
}
```

Comment: Did you also upload the image as well as the .html file? HTML files need these resources on the server along with the HTML file itself.

Comment: can you put the website link ?

Comment: all images are loaded, there is no error on conssole for me

Comment: @John how about http://www.carnin.co.za/outdoor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website loads fine. Your images are far too big (loading a 900Kb image for a 300x300px space is very inefficient) but on some pages the images do not load- error 404, so you need to check your links are CasE SensiTiVe

What you have is some thumbnail images are defined as `images/gallery/outdoor3.jpg` which works and exists, and is 1500x1500 size so plenty big enough, but your Lightbox full size image is looking for `images/gallery/outdoor/3.jpg` which doesn't exist. You need to double check your link addresses!!

From your code:

```
<!-- Lightbox -->
        <img src="images/gallery/outdoor/1.jpg" width="600" height="450"/>

 ...

<!-- thumbnail -->
    <img src="images/gallery/outdoor/outdoor1.jpg" width="170" height="170" />
```

Your addresses are different, and they probably should be the same as the thumbnail above is using a 1500x1500 image and showing it at 170x170 size, when the image is plenty big enough to be the lightbox target.

Also I highly suggest scrapping all your messy inline javascript and [using Lightbox 2](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2).

Comment: Thanks, got it working perfectly and scrapped the repititive script. Lightbox 2 worked perfectly.